# Remove Cypress data-cy attribute

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, cypress, e2e-testing

How to remove cypress "data-cy" from the production source code?
I have tried to use  [this](https://github.com/ivoiv/remove-data-cy) but it's hampering dynamic attributes.

I would be very grateful if you all can help me out.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

If your project uses Babel, you should be able to use [babel-plugin-react-remove-properties](https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-plugin-react-remove-properties) to remove `data-cy` and any other attributes/properties you want to hide away.